# Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 773ms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

My client app sends JSON encoded POST to rails server but the server shows 406 error and doesn't respond to json.

**UsersController create**

```
# POST /users
# POST /users.json
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**Rails console:**

```
Started POST "/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-21 16:38:47 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"", "available"=>"true", "email"=>"", "sex"=>"male", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = '' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 773ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: One thing I would suggest is to turn off CSRF token authenticity. To do this, go to the controller that renders the json and add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`. Adjust accordingly like you would with any other filter. This is assuming of course you can't produce the CSRF token in the app that sends JSON to Rails.

Comment: Turning off [cross-site request forgery protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) does not sound like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 3):

Going to try to answer this a while later in case anyone sees it. I've run into this problem over and over even when I've only had JSON as the format option at the bottom of my controller (like this in your example):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
end
```

Even when calling it explicitly with **`$.getJSON`** on my requests which does call it with JSON data types.

The trick I found was calling it with .json on my page name.

```
 $.getJSON('controllername-your-calling.json?', function(json){
      //do your stuff...
 });
```

Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `respond_to :json, only: [:create]` at the top of your controller. You may need to add `respond_to :html` for the actions that take HTML.