# Rails render_to giving 406 not acceptable error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter

So, I've been trying to rectify my option of hiding a tweet. It worked once but since I didn't save it at the time, I lost whatever my approach was.

My function is pretty simple, you click hide and it hides a tweet. Here's what I have in the controller;

```
def hide
    @newtweet = Newtweet.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:stauts, 'new')

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {flash[:notice] = "We've archives your tweet for later."}
    end 
end
```

Here's what I've got for my link;

```
<%= link_to "hide", hide_url(:id => tweetsy.id), :class => "btn btn-warning btn-sm hideit hidden-xs", :remote => true %>
```

and lastly, here's what's in my routes for that link;

```
match '/dashboard/hide/:id' => 'dashboards#hide', :as => :hide
```

I've got the def hide sitting in my dashboard controller.. and it works, as soon as I add

```
respond_to do |format|

end
```

even... it all gives me

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

No idea, how I got it working before and I'm about to pull my hair out. If I add format.js .. same old thing. If I remove

```
respond_to do |format|
end
```

it all works.. even with the above left it, still hides it, but I get a blank screen rather then a nice ajax happening.

Comment: When an action has an empty `respond_to` block the response status 406 is normal, as this empty block indicates that the action does not respond to any format. If you have `format.js...` line in you should get an error (status 500) because rails cannot find a matching view (at least if there is no app/views/THERESOURCE/hide.js.SOMEHANDLER file).

What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Margin - I'm simply updating my DB changing it's status from new to hidden.. so it doesn't display in overall view. The js is there to hide out the tweet and update without refreshing the page.

Comment: I meant, Martin, I'm sorry. Also, no matter if I have format.js or not, it seems as if as soon as I add the `respond_to` block, it quits and comes with `Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 7ms`

Comment: taking `respond_to do |format|` completely out, gives me the error of missing template. Little confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to finalize this, make sure all of your jQuery files are properly set and all collections of them are within your proper areas. In my case, I needed the following to make all `respond_to` work. I know, I know, silly of me.

**Your Application.js should have these.**

```
 /= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.touch-punch
//= require_tree .
```

and everything else Gem wise should be in your Gemfile or manually installed. Thanks to all for helping out on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm convinced that this is a rails bug because I've run into the same thing on JSON calls (as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882762/1208166)) even with the correct routes.

If you try to call your link explicitly with the local URL for hide, with a JS extension on the end see if you stop getting 406 errors.

```
<%= link_to "hide", "/hide.js?id=" + tweetsy.id.to_s, :class => "btn btn-warning btn-sm hideit hidden-xs", :remote => true %>
```

I know this seems like a hack, but I've had little success on several occasions with a similar problem with JSON. Maybe someone else has an answer with the fully qualified .js or .json on the URL path would make a difference. Or how to change that in the route itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually figured it out after going crazy on it and starting from scratch, it seems I must of left out the `/= require jquery_ujs` in my application.js.

Comment: It all works now as it should. My bad on this one, learn from mistakes what it's all about right? :) Thanks to both of you for helping out. BTW, creativereason = direct link or not, it was dropping 406 errors, I'm guessing because it was missing stuff from the ujs file for jquery.

Comment: I've seen that error before (when not using the ujs file). I've seen the 406 on JSON even with the ujs file linked. Glad yours is working?

Comment: It's working, quite weird though. Hope I don't see it again, took enough to figure it out lol... however seems that my ui touch don't work now. Maybe jQuery conflict, but that's another Q :) Thanks again!